# Print only 10 outputs per line

Tags: java, format, printf, output

I have a Printf formating question. I am to print only 10 numbers, before going to the next line and printing 10 more numbers and so on. with the end goal being like a table, with all the columns lining up and being aligned to the right. I am using a while statement as well. I have tried a few different things that I have found in my research, with no success. Would I use a different print statement for it other than Printf? Such as Print, or PrintLn? Also thought about using an If statement as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

```
    System.out.printf("Please enter a maximun integer value: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double n = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.printf("The number you entered was: %.0f \n", n); // Just to check if user input is correct

    double startNum = 0;
    double sqrt = startNum;

    System.out.printf("Squares less than %.0f are: ", n);
    while ( sqrt < n) {
        sqrt = Math.pow(startNum, 2);
        System.out.printf("%6.0f", sqrt);
        startNum ++;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should keep track of how many you've printed and start a new line after every 10th one.

Comment: Clearly if you're wanting to print 10 per line, you're going to need to keep track of the number you're printing, right? And when you print the 10th, you start a new line and reset your counter, wouldn't you think?

Comment: @KenWhite Or mod by 10.

Comment: @shmosel: True. You still need a counter to mod by 10.

Comment: @KenWhite Most definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a MOD condition, You can ensure 10 output per line.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Please enter a maximun integer value: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double n = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.printf("The number you entered was: %.0f \n", n); // Just to check if user input is correct

        double startNum = 0;
        double sqrt = startNum;

        System.out.printf("Squares less than %.0f are: ", n);
        while (sqrt < n) {
            sqrt = Math.pow(startNum, 2);
            if(startNum != 0 && startNum % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.printf("%6.0f", sqrt);
            startNum++;
        }
    }
}
```

> Output -
>
> Please enter a maximun integer value: 150
>
> The number you entered was: 150
>
> Squares less than 150 are:      0     1     4     9    16    25   36  49 64    81
>
> 121   144   169

Comment: Thank you for your help! I thought you would have to use an If statement, but I wasn't too sure how it would be set up. Seeing it now, it makes sense.

Comment: There are different ways to do this, Mod is just one of the straight forward option.

Comment: The first line is correct. Although, every line after only has 9 numbers.

Comment: @Sig.1855, Did you locate the root cause. Try, See the above edited answer only after you gave enough try.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( sqrt < n) {
    sqrt = Math.pow(startNum, 2);
    System.out.printf("%6.0f", sqrt);
    startNum ++;

    if(startNum%10==0){
        System.out.printf("/n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This would print only 9 values in first line

Comment: Please also add some explanation to the answer.